# Splitting the results into separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view, sql-server-2008r2-express

I need a view compatible SQL query to accomplish the following result (View 1).

```
Table 1:
--------------
ID |    Folder
--------------
1  |    foo
2  |    bar

Table 2:
-------------------------------------
ID |    Table1_ID | Name    |   Right
-------------------------------------
1  |    1         | fooUser |   W
2  |    2         | barUser |   R

View 1:
-------------------------------
Folder  |   fooUser  |  barUser
-------------------------------
foo     |     W      |
bar     |            |    R
```

I was only able to do so with custom functions, but I can only use this as storage procedures. I want to bind the result to a GridView.
I hope anybody can help me out.

Comment: If you expect it to be dynamic  when a third row is added to Table 2 (and expecting a new column to appear) you're not going to get it from a view (or any other object composable into larger queries) - the query within a view can only be a static query, and any particular static query always produces results with the same "shape" - a fixed number of columns, with the names and data types of those columns also fixed.

Comment: Surely I need dynamic data. I was aware that my attempt is impossible, because I didn't find any possible solution. Thank you for clearing that up for me. Dunno if I should create a new topic, but I'll ask anyway: Could the Entity Framework do the task for me? Or is creating a datatable at runtime the most common solution?

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you want to have values converted into columns, use `PIVOT`. Here you will need a select:

```
SELECT Folder, [fooUser], [baruser]
FROM (SELECT t.Folder, tt.* FROM one t JOIN two tt ON t.ID = tt.Table1_ID) AS source
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Rightt)
  FOR Name IN (fooUser, barUser)
) AS PivotTable;
```

Apply it to `CREATE VIEW ... AS` and it should work.

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79fb71/8)**

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I forgot to mention that I'm talking about dynamic data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to pivot the data from rows into columns:

```
select t1.folder,
  max(case when t2.name = 'fooUser' then [right] else '' end) fooUser,
  max(case when t2.name = 'barUser' then [right] else '' end) barUser
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
  on t1.id = t2.Table1_ID
group by t1.folder;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c5326/2).

If you need a dynamic solution, then you will need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Name) 
                    from table2
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT folder, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select t1.folder,
                t2.name, t2.[right]
              from table1 t1
              inner join table2 t2
                on t1.id = t2.Table1_ID
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max([right])
                for name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c5326/4)

Comment: Because I need dynamic data, I cannot use your solution neither. But I would like to know the difference in speed between your solution and the one from @makciook

Comment: Problem is that i cannot use dynamic SQL as view and stored procedures as a datasource for my control.

Comment: @Bonzai There is no way to perform this dynamically without using dynamic SQL in a stored procedure.

Comment: @Bonzai "I need dynamic data" ... "I can't use dynamic SQL" ... you are a walking contradiction. If you want dynamic columns you need dynamic SQL, or you need to change your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the statement from @Damien_The_Unbeliever.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here is a stupid answer, but it works :)  I recommend using PIVOT though @makciook.

```
select a.Folder,
       foo.[Right] fooUser,
       bar.[Right] barUser
  from one a
  left join two foo on a.ID = 1 and foo.ID = 1
  left join two bar on a.ID = 2 and bar.ID = 2
```